# jQuery syntax in js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I added a new element in the js.erb file and I am trying to assign a click event to the newly added element.

This is what I have in js.erb:

```
$("#<%= linkid %>").on("click", '<%= j function(event) {$(this).parent().next().toggle(); event.preventDefault();}) %>' );
```

I am getting syntax error using "$" writing the function. what is the fix here? If I have to put this function in a var within this file, how do I do it? Generally, is there a better way?

Update: error message

```
/create.js.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
....append= ( j function(event) {$(this).parent().next().toggle...
...                               ^
/create.js.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
...(); event.preventDefault();}) );@output_buffer.safe_concat('...
...                               ^):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things inside `<%= ... %>` are supposed to be Ruby expressions, not JavaScript. This:

```
<%= j function(event) {$(this).parent().next().toggle(); event.preventDefault();}) %>
```

doesn't need the ERB at all, that's just plain old JavaScript. Also, the second argument to jQuery's [`$(...).on('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be a JavaScript function, not a JavaScript string. You want this:

```
$("#<%= linkid %>").on("click", function(event) {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. however I get the same syntax error -shown in the post

Comment: @user1441662: That error doesn't match the code in my answer, it looks like an error message from your original code.

Comment: thanks again, yeah, the line number doesn't match but it is pointing to the $(this) usage in this code. for reference, if I remove this code, the rest compiles fine.

Comment: yes, I copied the exact code and pasted it in my js.erb file, I just happened to have few other lines before it, hence the line number mismatch - thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17987/discussion-between-user1441662-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: can you post all the content of create.js.erb?